# how to set a NSIndexPath after it has been created

Tags: ios, macos, uitableview, nsindexpath

i created a NSIndexPath using:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

now i want to index thru a UITableView by modifying this path, i can't find any API calls that set values in a NSIndexPath

seems like a huge waste to allocate a new NSIndexPath every time, especialy as i'm actually using it to make a call that doesn't allocate any memory (an addition to the protocol)

Answer (score 2):

> I can't find any API calls that set values in an NSIndexPath.

Because there aren't - NSIndexPath is immutable.

> seems like a huge waste to allocate a new NSIndexPath every time

It is. Sorry for that. Wrap it into an `@autoreleasepool { }` if you care about this.

Comment: I could imagine they use some pool of objects for common paths and you wouldnt REALLY get a new object each time. same as with numbers

Comment: @Daij-Djan Yes, this is a common optimization method (NSString does it as well), so it's most likely used, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

`NSIndexPath` is immutable.  Just create a new one each time.  Then, if you have a performance problem, use Instruments to figure out whether creating index paths is part of the problem.

**Only after you have verified that creating index paths is a problem** should you consider creating a subclass of `NSIndexPath` that has its own storage for the indexes and provides mutation methods.  (UIKit does something like this internally with `UIMutableIndexPath`, but that class is not public.)